# Create Leave Management site using SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, approval-process

can anyone suggest me how to create a time sheet in share point online. My requirement is when we select a start date and end end date the total leave days has to been shown by subtracting start date from end date and then when a leave is approved by the manager then the approved leave has to subtracted from the Total leaves in a year and has to show the available leaves every time In new form

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :  Create SharePoint Team Site and create Custom List with Title **Employee Master**. Also maintain Total Leaves to be credited for particular User in the same list

Step 2 : Create another custom list with title **Leave Application** . Provide Add Permission to every user to the list

Step 3 :  Add Start Date and End Date column with type Date/Time and also add calculated column which calculates days between start date and end date. you can use this formula `=IF(OR(ISBLANK([startDate]),ISBLANK([EndDate])),"",DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],"D"))`

Step 4 : Create approval workflow on the List which would send the applied leave for approval to respective managers fetched from AD

Step 5 : Provide New Item form of **Leave Application** for user to Apply for the leave.

Step 6: On approval you can subtract the amount of leave from the employee master.

Step 7 :  You can also use CSOM and display to the user on New Form of **Leave Application** the amount of leave balance from **Employee Master**

And your job is done...